# How to disable a table from being deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a possible way on SQL-Server 2008 to disable certain tables from being deleted or entire database tables from being deleted or even the deletion of any database/table?

Comment: Deny potential deletees permission to so do?

Comment: How do I do that sir? I'm somewhat of a newbie on SQL, I know quite a bit but not enough to do that

Comment: Remove the drop privilege from users you don't want to be able to delete the table, or better, do the reverse and grant only the rights required to said users. Take a look at *How to deny drop permission for a table?*  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15846/how-to-deny-drop-permission-for-a-table

Comment: check out this link on [setting permissions for delete][1] and [this too][2]


  [1]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12277/deny-insert-delete-for-all-users-in-sql-server-2005
  [2]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15846/how-to-deny-drop-permission-for-a-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy answer is: don't give permission to drop tables to people who shouldn't have it. If you're afraid of someone who should be able to drop a table ACCIDENTALLY doing it, you could create a DDL trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE 
AS 
   PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop or alter tables!' 
   ROLLBACK
;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406(v=sql.105).aspx